# ImageDataGenerator doesn't generate enough samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am following F.Chollet book "Deep learning with python" and can't get one example working.
In particular, I am running an example from chapter "Training a convnet from scratch on a small dataset".
My training dataset has 2000 sample and I am trying to extend it with augmentation using ImageDataGenerator. Despite that my code is exactly the same, I am getting error:

> Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your
> dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs`
> batches (in this case, 10000 batches).

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# creating model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# model compilation
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
                metrics=['acc'])

# model.summary()

# generating trains and test sets with rescaling 0-255 -> 0-1
train_dir = 'c:\\Work\\Code\\Python\\DL\\cats_and_dogs_small\\train\\'
validation_dir = 'c:\\Work\\Code\\Python\\DL\\cats_and_dogs_small\\validation\\'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,)
# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        # This is the target directory
        train_dir,
        # All images will be resized to 150x150
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    print('data batch shape:', data_batch.shape)
    print('labels batch shape:', labels_batch.shape)
    break

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)
```

[Here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb) is the link to github page for this book samples. Where you can check the code as well.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and asking any advice. Thank you

Comment: `batch_size=32,` it should be `batch_size=20,`

Comment: this will force to use only real images. What about augmented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `batch_size` should be 20 not 32.

Since you have `steps_per_epoch = 100`, it will execute `next()` on train generator 100 times before going to next epoch.

Now, in `train_generator` the `batch_size` is `32`, so it can generate `2000/32` number of batches, given that you have `2000` number of training samples. And that is approximate `62`.

So on `63th` time executing `next()` on `train_generator` will give nothing and it will tell `Your input ran out of data;`

Ideally,

```
steps_per_epoch = total_traing_sample / batch_size
```

Comment: This is true if taking into account only real images but what ImageDataGenerator is then for? I though it should somehow extend training data set making many artificial samples by some transformations like shifting, rotating etc.

Comment: You are right. ImageDataGenerator is used to augment the image. Suppose on 1st epoch you will take one image A, in 2nd epoch when you will get image A, it will be rotated, zoomed, etc..effectively not original image.

Comment: Oh. So it doesn't make more images but when I call some particular image more than once, then it gives me augmented image? That explains everything actually. So, is it correct logic?

Comment: yes, it dosn't create new image. It just apply random transformation to the existing set only.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer described your issue well. I would like to add one point, you can also get the correct steps_per_epoch value by adding these lines.

```
train_steps = train_generator.__len__()
val_steps = validation_generator.__len__()
```

Comment: why not `len(validation_generator)`?

Comment: Yep, I think both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue while dealing with the data generation with augmentation.

The solutions provided above are true `steps_per_epoch = total_training_sample / batch_size`.

But since you are augmenting the images, I believe you would not mind passing the same image with different augmentations.

For me, I used the same keras version with tensorflow background as Chollet used and it removed this error. In that case, it will keep feeding you images indefinitely since it loop when it finishes from the available images.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. This is true when I want to use only real images. But what about image generator? How can I know how many augmented images will be added and which batch size should I use then. Maybe I have some wrong understanding of ImageDataGenerator but I thought that it should provide additional samples by augmenting initial images. Am I wrong here?